# Can someone please explain what this error means

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Getting this the following error:

```
0|animesoul  |   websocket.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSING;
0|animesoul  |                        ^
0|animesoul  | TypeError: Cannot set property 'readyState' of undefined
0|animesoul  |     at Socket.socketOnClose (/home/gibigbig/animesoul/app/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:781:24)
0|animesoul  |     at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
0|animesoul  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
0|animesoul  |     at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)
```

Not sure what file or event is causing the issue. I get that error randomly  but it crashes my node process. I don't even know how to debug it because its not really telling me anything of any particular use. Googling didnt really give much insight, about 3 other people have a similar issue and i suspect it has to do with duplicate connections but I would like to confirm please.

I have 4 nodes of this app running  in pm2 and it is being load balanced with nginx

app.js

```
    express = require('express'),
    exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
    client = require('./lib/discord.js'),
    site = require('./global.js'),
    serverio = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('./lib/io'),
    port = process.env.PORT ,
    redis = require('redis'),
    brooker = require('./broker')

let data = {};
var subscriber = redis.createClient([redacted]);
brooker();
subscriber.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    messages = JSON.parse(message);
    io.to(messages.room).emit(messages.event, messages)
});
client.on('ready', async () => {
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.set('env production');
    app.use("*", function (req, res, next) {
        return res.status(404).render('404', { data: data, user: req.user, layout: "main" });
    });
    io.attach(serverio);
    serverio.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:' + port);
    });

});
subscriber.subscribe("notifications");
process.on('SIGINT', async function () {
    process.exit();
});
```

/lib/io.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')();    
module.exports = io;
```

Comment: You didn't provide the full stack trace, which is problematic since the error is coming from the `ws` lib and we've got no way to find out where in your code this error was triggered. Also, please provide a [mcve] - as of now, your example is incomplete thus not reproducible

Comment: Thats where youre wrong. Here is the output I have from console.

https://imgur.com/ZWflC6E

Comment: This is why I can't debug, I have nothing to really go on.

Comment: At the very least the error sais quite explicitly that `websocket` is `undefined` instead of a valid object representing a websocket connection. That alone might be enough to narrow down the root issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update again:

Found an amazing package called "Longjohn" 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/longjohn

Which helped me get to the root of the problem. I no longer have any issue with this error. Sharing to save a life.

Answer (score 2):

```
0|animesoul  |   websocket.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSING;
0|animesoul  |                        ^
0|animesoul  | TypeError: Cannot set property 'readyState' of undefined
0|animesoul  |     at Socket.socketOnClose (/home/gibigbig/animesoul/app/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:781:24)
0|animesoul  |     at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
0|animesoul  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
0|animesoul  |     at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)
```

To explain the error, not the cause:

This is a TypeError. Namely that you cannot set a property (`readyState`) to `undefined` or `null` objects.

The error is displaying a stack trace, showing that the particular line of code is from file `/home/gibigbig/animesoul/app/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js`. The presence of `node_modules` shows it is the node modules, "engine.io"'s use of the "ws" library, and the line is 781. Might be a duplicate of [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1564)?

The rest of the trace helps a little, but not much. It started in NodeJS (the `net` library) on TCP close, which emitted something ("Socket.emit"), which was handled by the `ws` library "Socket.socketOnClose". Best you can tell this exception occurred when a socket was closing.

You could also try adding an [unhandledException handler](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) to your process. You might get some more information that way, or decide the error is mundane and after logging, just ignore it! (Typically that is a bad idea, because it will hide other important errors).

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain, though i knew most of what you are saying already, that link to the exception handler might be useful, so thank you for that.

Comment: Also i dont think its a duplicate of that github issue because my code handles multiple connections just fine. I just occasionally get that undefined websocket issue. Wish it told me the file responsible though, my project is quite large and its very difficult to debug on very little info.